# Query values in two arrays and merge them together

Tags: json, shell, merge, jq

I'm trying to query 2 separate arrays in a JSON using a `shell` script and merge them together to potentially open as a .csv in excel.

Here is a sample of the JSON:

```json
{
  "Defaults": {
    "Timestamps": [
      1677801540,
      1677801480,
      1677801420
    ]
  },
  "MetricDataForAccount": [
    {
      "Values": [
        2920126.416862745,
        2920285.9993725484,
        2920305.409303922
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently the following `jq` query is working for me but not in the intended format:

```bash
jq -r '. | "\(.Defaults.Timestamps) \(.MetricDataForAccount[].Values)"'
```

> Output `[1677801540,1677801480,1677801420] [2920126.416862745,2920285.9993725484,2920305.409303922]`

The intended goal would be for the output to looks as follows:

```
1677801540, 2920126.416862745
1677801480, 2920285.9993725484
1677801420, 2920305.409303922
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `transpose` the arrays to align their items:

```bash
jq -r '[.Defaults.Timestamps, .MetricDataForAccount[].Values] | transpose[] | @csv'
```

Or iterate manually (e.g. using `to_entries` to access the indices as `.key`):

```bash
jq -r '
  .Defaults.Timestamps as $timestamps
  | .MetricDataForAccount[].Values
  | to_entries[] | [$timestamps[.key], .value]
  | @csv
'
```

Output:

```
1677801540,2920126.416862745
1677801480,2920285.9993725484
1677801420,2920305.409303922
```

Comment: Sensational  \(^o^)/